# De-aliasing two-factor interactions in a Plackett-Burman design

Tags: experiment-design, confounding, fractional-factorial

what I've got so far is a 2-level experiment design with 10 factors and 32 experiments, which is made of a resolution III Plackett-Burman design that I folded (complete foldover) so that it is a resolution IV design now. After carrying out the experiments and analyzing the results we came to the conclusion that we need to investigate more on the 2-factor interactions, which as of yet are aliased with each other (as it is always the case in resolution 4 designs). Because of that we now want to do another foldover.

What we are unsure about is whether or not one can just use regular one- or two-column foldovers or if there are special techniques used for Plackett-Burman designs. Especially because Placket-Burman designs (diffent to fractional factorials) have columns which are not fully aliased but correlated with a Pearson correlation of 0.5/-0.5.

So do these partial aliases somehow need to be treated differently when de-aliasing? And how much of problem are they in the first place (for models built from that data)?